# CALayer values not applied to UIControl

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, calayer, nscoder

**WORKGROUND**

Create a `UIView` with `UILabel` and `UIButton`. Here i have set layer properties of `UIButton` below:

```
[self.btnDropdown.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[self.btnDropdown.layer setBorderWidth:0.8f];
[self.btnDropdown.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
```

Now i am saving this custom view into file  using `NSCoding` and load the same. This control is displayed in `UITableViewCell`.

**ISSUE**:

All the details of custom view like `UILable` title, size, background color etc. Same for the `UIButton` are retrieved from file. But `CALayer` related details which i have set for `UIButton` are not retrieved.

**Before saving to file:**

[image]

**After getting from file:**

[image]

So I am not clear about that `CALayer` properties are manage with `UIButton` object.

Is these details (`CALAyer` values) are visible only at run time? Or i am missing something?

Please add a comment if question is unclear to you.

**EDIT:**

Previously i have not provide more information to reduce the complexity of the question. Below is complete hierarchy of my implementation.

**NSObject --> Custom View --> UIButton --> CALayer**

1) First `NSObject` class is a bean class. Which contains some variables (i called it Property). This properties are meta details of Custom view. `There is one variable "parentView" is use to store Custom view.`

2) Custom view: This is `UIView` class which contains `UILabel` and `UIButton`

Now bean class object (Property) is stored in file and retried. So that i can use variable `parentView` to load Custom view.

And as per question about the `UIButton` is embedded in that Custom view.

Comment: Please check the result of this method `- (BOOL)shouldArchiveValueForKey:(NSString *)key` for the layer of your custom view. The key name will be `borderColor` etc. before archiving your custom view

Comment: @croyneaus4u: Tried that, no change :(

Comment: Can you please show me what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figure it out:**

Here button shown in images custom views. I used to save these control in local database with `BLOB`.

Thing is that these views object/instance are stored in database with some properties.

Now when i retrieve them and add them to any view as a subview their `-init` method is not getting called. (Any how i figure that out) and called `-init` method for these views.